# Menu doesnt work as intended, background, menu in the middle of the screen

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

Currently trying to configure a menu for smaller resolutions, I.E mobile devices and such.

The problem I'm currently having tho is, the background from the menu in full size, background: url(shad2.png)  is showing on the smaller version aswell, and I can't seem to find a way to remove it.

My second question I have is. How do I create a "pop-out" window for my menu + the same look as this menu has http://osvaldas.info/examples/drop-down-navigation-touch-friendly-and-responsive/#nav  SCALE THE WINDOW DOWN AND YOU'll GET FEEL! I want my menu to have the same feel, but with my colours and such! Cause right now my menu pops out in the middle of the screen, instead of directly under the menu button! Thanks

Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yD7dM/

Here is my current code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"xml:lang="sv">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <title>egen hemsida</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="mobilemenu.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="screen.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".nav-button").on('click',function () {
            $(".nav-button,.nav").toggleClass("open");
            });    
        });
        </script>
</head>
<body>

<button class="nav-button">Toggle Navigation</button>





<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="#">Program</a>
  <ul>
<li><a href="#">Teknik</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Naturvetenskap</a></li>
<li><a href="#">El</a></li>
</ul></li>
  <li><a href="#">Nösnäs</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Schema</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Matsal</a></li>
   </ul>


<style>.xg_module_body img {margin:0!important;}</style>
<span class="bilder">
<div align="center"><table cellpadding="0" width="150"  cellspacing="0"><tr>
<td><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="facebookpic.png" title="Gilla våran Facebook sida" width="35" height="35" border="0"></a></td>

<td><a href="#"target="_blank"><img src="googlepic.png" title="Gilla oss på googlde+" width="35" height="35" border="0"></a></td>

<td><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="twitterpic.png" title="Följ oss på Twitter" width="35" height="35" border="0"></a></td>

<td><a href="#" target=""><img src="rsspic.png" width="35" height="35" border="0" title="Följ våran RSS"></a></td>
</tr>
</table></div>
</span>



</body>
</html>
```

CSS - Full size

```
 .bilder {
    position: absolute;
    top: 58px;
    left: 110px;

}




* { margin:0;
padding:0;
}

html {height: 100%;}

body{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ccc), to(#fff));

}

.navbox {
    position: relative;
    float: left;


}

/* Första boxarna*/
ul.nav {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    width: 170px;
    position: relative;
    top: :0px;
    left: 100px;
    z-index:0;
    padding: 100px 0 50px 0;
    background: url(shad2.png) no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: 50% 100%;
    display: list-item;

}




li {
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}

/* När jag drar musen över */
ul.nav li a  {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;

    color: #174867;
    padding: 7px 15px 7px 15px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;

    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 2px #888;
}

ul.nav li a:hover {
    background: #ebebeb url(border.png) no-repeat;
    color: #67a5cd;
    padding: 7px 15px 7px 30px;
}
ul.nav li ul { 
display:none;
}
ul.nav li:hover ul { 
display:block;
position:relative;
left:5px;top:0px;
list-style: none;
z-index:999;
}

ul.nav li ul li
{ 
background:#888;

}
```

Css- Mobile

```
.nav-button { display: none; } /* hide the navigation button by default */

@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 475px) {
.bilder { display: none;}

    /* Navigation Button
    -------------------------------------------------------- */

    .nav-button {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        top: 2px;
        left: 7px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 35px;
        background: url('intebilder/menu-icon-large.png'), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,.2));
        background: url('intebilder/menu-icon-large.png'),    -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,.2));
        background: url('intebilder/menu-icon-large.png'),     -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,.2));
        background: url('intebilder/menu-icon-large.png'),      -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,.2));
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 21px, 100%;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: 0 none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.1);
        box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,.7) inset;
        border-radius: 5px;
        z-index: 999;
        text-indent: -9999px;
    }
    .nav-button:hover { 
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1); 
    }
    .nav-button.open {
        background: url('intebilder/close-icon-large.png'), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,.2));
        background: url('intebilder/close-icon-large.png'),    -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,.2));
        background: url('intebilder/close-icon-large.png'),     -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,.2));
        background: url('intebilder/close-icon-large.png'),      -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,.2));
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 21px, 100%;

    }

    /* Navigation Bar
    -------------------------------------------------------- */

    body { 
    padding-top: 10px; 

    } 

    ul.nav{
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
        background-color: #238be3; /* change the menu color */
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,.2));
        background-image:  -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,.2));
        background-image:  -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,.2));
        background-image:  -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,.2));
        display: block;
        height: 50px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;

        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 300px;
        z-index: 998;
        clear: both;
        list-style: none;
    }
    ul.nav li {
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
        font-family: Arial;
    }
    ul.nav li a {
        display: block;
        width: 90%;
        padding: 10px 5%;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
        border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.1); 
    }
    ul.nav li a:hover {
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        border-top-color: transparent;
    }
    ul.nav > li:first-child {
        border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    }

    /* Toggle the navigation bar open  */

    ul.nav.open { 
        height: auto; 
        padding-top: 50px;
    }
    ul.nav.open li { 
        display: block; 
    }

    /* Submenus – optional .parent class indicates dropdowns */

    ul.nav > li:hover > a {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        border-bottom-color: transparent;
    }
    ul.nav li.parent > a:after {
        content: "▼";
        color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
        float: right;
    }
    ul.nav li.parent > a:hover {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.75);
    }
    ul.nav li ul {
        display: none;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        border-top: 0 none;
        padding: 0;
    }
    ul.nav li ul a {
        border: 0 none;
        font-size: 12px;
        padding: 10px 5%;
        font-weight: normal;
    }
    ul.nav li:hover ul {
        display: block;
        border-top: 0 none;
    }

} /* End Mobile Styles */
```

Comment: create a [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yD7dM/ There we go!